# Hudson Backup Plugin - Backup copy to remote system with scripting

Tags: backup, hudson, jenkins

I am using [Hudson Backup Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Backup+Plugin), it is working fine, but I have to put one copy of backup file in another Linux machine and one copy in local machine. It is not providing any pre-script or post-script facility. Can someone please suggest to me how can I do this?

A better plugin or script, instead of Backup Plugin, is also ok.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could create another job in hudson to do one of the backups. Then you could link them so that when one runs the other runs after.

Local Backup -> Remote Backup